# Knowing the number of iterations needed for convergence in SVR scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to optimize an SVR model and facing  a problem because of overfitting, to overcome this I have tried to decrease the number of iterations instead of leaving it until convergence.

To compare the both models I need the number of iterations for both cases.
How can I know the number of iterations needed for convergence in the case it is open (max_iter=-1)?

This is my code:

```
model_1=SVR(kernel='rbf', C=316, epsilon=0, gamma=0.003162,max_iter=2500)
model_1.fit(tr_sets[:,:2],tr_sets[:,2])
print(model_1.score)
model_2=SVR(kernel='rbf', C=316, epsilon=0, gamma=0.003162,max_iter=-1)
model_2.fit(tr_sets[:,:2],tr_sets[:,2])
print(model_2.score)
```

**Edit:** the problem now is solved for IPython IDE by setting `verbose=2` but still need to be viewed in Jupyter notebook, spyder or to be written to an external file as the verbose option seems only to work with IPython IDE

Comment: (1) In general you should use more regulization and go for full convergence (2) There is no way of calculating the needed number of iterations a-priori (of course that's also heavily dependent on the used algorithm). (3) In the a-posteriori setting, i don't see something in the API (i think the SGD-approaches differ; but SVR is using liblinear/libsvm internally, in your case libsvm because of rbf kernel), but you could try to modify the code or activate verbosity for this (i think).

Comment: (4) And of course: always use cross-validation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see the progress of your SVR, enter `verbose=2` to the constructor of SVR - **notice this can make progress slower by a magnitude**

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import numpy as np

n_samples, n_features = 10, 5
np.random.seed(0)
y = np.random.randn(n_samples)
X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)
clf = SVR(C=1.0, epsilon=0.2,verbose=2)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Output will be

```
optimization finished, #iter = 4
obj = -4.366801, rho = -0.910470
nSV = 7, nBSV = 5
```

Where `#iter` is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your code but I am not getting the information you get. I am using jupyter notebook from Anaconda and scikit-learn version 0.18.1. What do you think the reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean "not getting the information"? Did you put `verbose=2` in the constructor, and did not get the code of my output..?

Comment: The output I am getting is: 

SVR(C=1.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, epsilon=0.2, gamma='auto',  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=5)

Comment: lets continue this conversation in chat, I will invite you

Comment: I can't find you in chat... please enter chat.stackoverflow.com and look for room "SVR iteration" and enter it

Comment: the problem now is solved for IPython IDE but still need to be viewed in Jupyternotebook or to be written to an external file

Comment: glad I helped, I would be grateful if you marked it as answer "v", which is just below the rating - for future users.
I don't know why Jupyter does not display it, but that is another question :)

Answer (score 0):

In modern versions of Scikit-learn you have the `n_iter_` attribute ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)) which it's a ndarray of shape `n_classes * (n_classes - 1) // 2` with all the needed iterations to fit all the models for every class:

```py
import numpy as np

model = SVR(...parameters)
model.fit(x, y)
print('Iterations needed:', np.sum(model.n_iter_))
```